# How to multi-thread a brute force java password program

Tags: java, multithreading, passwords, processor

I created a program for for my 11th grade computer science project where I made a java password cracker that brute-forces the password. However, I would like to get some advice on how to multi-thread my java program (code provided below) to speed up the brute-force process. If it helps at all I am running a i7-3770 processor by Intel and it is quad-core but has 2 threads per core so 8 possible threads at once.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class pwcracker
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
Random rand = new Random();

Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

 String pw, choices, guess;
long tries;
int j, length;

System.out.println("Enter a password that is up to 5 chars and contains no numbers: ");
pw = "" + scan.nextLine();
length = pw.length();

choices = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
tries = 0;
guess = "";

System.out.println("Your pw is: " + pw);
System.out.println("The length of your pw is: " + length);

System.out.println("for TEST- Guess: " + guess + "pw :"+pw);


 if (guess !=  pw){

 while  (guess !=  pw) 
 { 
    j = 0;
    guess = "";

    while ( j < length )
    {
        guess = guess + choices.charAt( rand.nextInt ( choices.length() ) );
        j = j + 1;

    if (guess == pw)
 {
   System.out.println("Match found, ending loop..");
   break;
 }

    }
            System.out.println("2 Guess: " + guess + " pw :"+pw); 

    tries = tries + 1;                      
}
}
System.out.println("Here is your password: " + guess);
System.out.println("It took " + tries + " tries to guess it.");
 }
 }
```

Comment: you can't use == to compare strings in java. you need to use string1.equals(string2)

Comment: Programs aren't hyperthreaded, processors are hyperthreaded. And processor threads aren't any more related to software threads than cores are.

Comment: Of yeah sorry, I forgot to mention that i updated the code on my end to use .equals rather than == so that isnt a bug anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a parallel processing solution but a much more optimised brute force approach. You can consider changing the Iterator to a Spliterator. If time permits I will possibly give a Spliterator approach in a following post.

```
package pwcracker;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pwcracker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pw;
        int length;

        System.out.println("Enter a password that is up to 5 chars and contains no numbers: ");
        pw = "" + scan.nextLine();
        length = pw.length();

        SequentialPatternGenerator generator = new SequentialPatternGenerator(length);

        generator.forEachRemaining(test -> {if(pw.equals(test)) {
            System.out.println("Your password: " + test );
        }});

    }
}

class SequentialPatternGenerator implements Iterator<String> {

    private static final char[] CHOICES = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
        'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};

    private static final int MAX_INDEX = CHOICES.length - 1;
    private boolean keepProducing = true;
    private final int[] indexes;

    public SequentialPatternGenerator(final int length) {
        indexes = new int[length];
        initIndexes();
    }

    private void initIndexes() {
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
            indexes[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (!keepProducing) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
            if (indexes[i] < MAX_INDEX) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        if (!keepProducing || !hasNext()) {
            return null;
        }

        String next = produceString();
        adjustIndexes();

        return next;
    }

    public void stop() {
        keepProducing = false;
    }

    private String produceString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(CHOICES[indexes[i]]);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void adjustIndexes() {
        int i;
        for(i = 0 ; i < indexes.length ; i++) {
            if(indexes[i] < MAX_INDEX) {
                indexes[i] = indexes[i] + 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        for(int j=0; j < i; j++) {
            indexes[j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks, that is a lot faster!

Answer (score 0):

First you want to reduce as many unnecssary function calls in your loop as possible. For example choices.length can be stored as variable in memory say int choice = choice.length. This will optomize your program because each time the computer does not have to calculate length it is already there stored in memory for it to use.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with the threaded route, then I would set this up as a [producer-consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) algorithm. At a high lever, we have producer threads creating work, and we have consumer threads doing the work, and we have a shared queue object that we use to transfer work units from the producers to the consumers.

In your case, since your sample space is relatively small (permutations with repetition of length 5), I would have a single producer thread. This will also help keep things simple if you use my suggestion below. [This tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/1034/java-blockingqueue-example-implementing-producer-consumer-problem) looks pretty simple as a starting point for you. As far as the total number of threads to use, start small and play around with different numbers of threads.

I see that you are randomly creating strings to check against. However, as this can create a lot of repeated and redundant checks, I suggest using permutations. That is, you need all permutations of the characters of the alphabet of length 5. I found this library that does [combinations and permutations](https://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/#2._Permutations_with_repetitions). This will allow you to get all possible arrangements without repetition. Something like this:

```
// Create the initial vector of 26 elements (alphabet)
ICombinatoricsVector<char> originalVector = Factory.createVector(new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'z' });

// Create the generator by calling the appropriate method in the Factory class. 
// Set the second parameter as 5, since we will generate 5-elemets permutations
Generator<char> gen = Factory.createPermutationWithRepetitionGenerator(originalVector, 5);

// Print the result
for (ICombinatoricsVector<char> perm : gen)
   System.out.println( perm ); //combine the elements of perm into a single string and add to your queue
```

(Warning: I didn't test the above)

Edit: I had to look up the difference between combinations and permutations while thinking about this :) I found this link useful as a simple refresher: http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html